# C++ how can I refactor this?

Tags: c++

I have the code below in my test code in many places:

```
  //
  // Make a function call while expecting an exception should be thrown
  //
  bool exceptionThrown = false;
  try
  {
    expectNotEqual(someData, anotherData, methodName);
  }
  catch(std::logic_error&)
  {
    exceptionThrown = true;
  }
  if(!exceptionThrown)
    throw std::logic_error(methodName+"exception not thrown");
```

It would be nice (more readable, concise) if I could encapsulate all that, and do something like:

```
  exceptionShouldBeThrown(expectNotEqual(someData, anotherData, methodName));
```

I dont want to use macro ...does anyone know how I could achieve the one-liner above with C++?

Comment: Why not make an `expectEqual` instead?

Comment: Without a (nice) binding system (like Boost Bind), what you want is impossible without macro's.

Comment: Exceptions *should* be thrown? Values *not* equal? The negative logic hurts.

Comment: Why not rewrite `expectNotEqual` to return a value, instead of throwing an exception?

Comment: I do have an expectEqual. But...I am using TDD to implement the someData operator != and ==. I'm trying to use reverse logic to test its correctness. e.g. if 2 objects are ==, but when I test it with != and it returns true, something is wrong, and that's why I throw an exception. I hope you guys get what I mean.

Comment: This is test code - the OP is trying to ensure that his methods do in fact throw exceptions (as expected) when he passes in invalid input. Obviously sometimes exceptions are thrown, so suggesting rewriting all code not to throw them is a bit silly (even if in this case it could be done).

Comment: @GMan, I do have the Boost library for my project, though I don't know how to use Bind. Would be nice if I could see an example relevant to this particular case.

Comment: @Jefromi understood the rationale of my question! Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know you say no macro's, but why? They exist for generating code:

```
#define SHOULD_THROW(x, name) \
    { \
        bool didThrow = false; \
        try \
        { \
            x; \
        } \
        catch(...) { didThrow = true; } \
        \
        if (!didThrow) \
            throw std::logic_error(name " did not throw."); \
    }

SHOULD_THROW(expectNotEqual(someData, anotherData), "expectNotEqual")
```

If you really don't want to use macros, you need to make a functor to call:

```
template <typename Func>
void should_throw(Func pFunc, const std::string& pName)
{
    bool didThrow = false;
    try
    {
        pFunc();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        didThrow = true;
    }

    if (!didThrow)
        throw std::logic_error(pName + " did not throw.");
}
```

[Boost Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bind/bind.html) helps here:

```
should_throw(boost::bind(expectNotEqual, someData, anotherData),
                "expectNotEqual");
```

Of course anything that makes a functor works, like lambda's, etc. But if Boost is available, just use their [testing library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html):

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test)
{
    BOOST_CHECK_THROW(expectNotEqual(someData, anotherData) , std::logic_error);
}
```

Comment: @GMan, I think you have a point about macro. Perhaps I should just use  macro.

Comment: @Sha: If you have boost available, I definitely recommend using their test library.

Comment: Thanks for showing me an example of how to use macro, Boost Bind, and Boost test.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions are for things that are exceptional. That is, something you wouldn't expect during run time, e.g., out of memory error.  You don't want to use an exception to test for common things at run time.  Just have expectNotEqual return a true/false on success:

```
if (expectNotEqual(someData, anotherData, methodName))
{
  //handle success
}
else
{
  //handle failure (which would include someData==anotherData)
}
```